# converting degrees minutes seconds to decimal degrees adds too much precision

Tags: coordinates, gis

I'm converting coordinates from degrees minutes seconds to decimal degrees. However, in the process of converting, the resulting coordinates are much more precise than they should be. 
How can I correctly incorporate the lack of precision?

For example, some coordinates lacking seconds:

143 DEG 10 MIN W, 28 DEG 25 MIN N

To convert, I would do the following:

```
143.1667 <- 143 + 10/60
28.41667 <- 28 + 25/60
```

But really, the longitude could be anywhere from:

```
143.1667 <- 143 + 10/60 + 0/3600
```

to

```
143.1831 <- 143 + 10/60 + 59/3600
```

It seems like I should be rounding these coordinates so that they do not convey artificial precision...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can round it just like this:

```
double roundedValue = Math.floor(unroundedValue * 10) / 10;
// 123.456 --> 123.4
```

If you use "100" instead of "10", you will get a a precision of two digits.